# How does adding to none work?

Tags: perl

While trying to reduce some default hash code, I came to discover that you could add to none to produce none or to produce what you're adding to it. Is there a particular reason for this? Will this change on different architectures or can I rely on this ability?

```
DB<1> print none + 1

DB<2> print 1 + none
1
```

And just for those that are curious, this is how I'm using it

```
foreach (@someArray) {
    unless ($someHash{$_}++) {
        $someHash{$_} = 1;
    }
}
```

as a reduction for

```
foreach (@someArray) {
    if (exists $someHash{$_}) {
        $someHash{$_}++;
    } else {
        $someHash{$_} = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `unless ($someHash{$_}++)` will set `$someHash{$_}` to 1 if `$_` is not a valid key in `%someHash` making the conditional code irrelevant. Why? Because `$someHash{$_}` of a key that doesn't exist that gets incremented [auto-vivifies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) the key and incrementing undef returns 1.

Comment: @PP Well how about that. That really simplifies that code block. I'll take my code samples away until I find better samples. I'm still curious about the whole none+1 thing.

Comment: Sorry @agweber I have to rollback the code you provided so the question makes sense to others who stumble upon it. If you want to add an update at the bottom feel free.

Comment: @PP But you've just proven to me that the code sample is irrelevant. I feel that the debug tests are enough to provide information for those that stumble upon this to understand what I'm asking about..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not doing what you think you are doing. These two statements:

```
print none + 1
print 1 + none
```

Are not as straightforward as you might think. Because you have warnings turned off, you do not know what they do. Lets try them out in the command prompt, with warnings turned on (`-w` switch):

```
$ perl -lwe'print none + 1'
Unquoted string "none" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 1.
Name "main::none" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
print() on unopened filehandle none at -e line 1.

$ perl -lwe'print 1 + none'
Unquoted string "none" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 1.
Argument "none" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
1
```

In the first case, `none`, which is a bareword, is interpreted as a file handle, and the print statement fails because we never opened a file handle with that name. In the second case, the bareword `none` is interpreted as a string, which gets converted to a number by the addition operator `+`, and that number will be zero `0`.

You can further clarify this by supplying a specific file handle for the first case:

```
$ perl -lwe'print STDOUT none + 1'
Unquoted string "none" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 1.
Argument "none" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
1
```

Which demonstrates that there is no real difference between `none + 1` and `1 + none`.